# A built-in Object in Rust

Tags: rust

Rust doesn't have built-in `Object` type I take it? If so, how do I, say, create a HashMap of "something" that in Java would be `Object`:

```
  fn method1(my_hash_map: HashMap<&str, ???>) { ... } // Rust
  void method1(Map<String, Object> myMap) { ... } // Java
```

Comment: You are looking for [`any`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/any/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a HashMap that can mix values of many different types, you'll have to use `Any`. The most direct equivalent to `Map<String, Object>` would be `HashMap<String, Box<Any>>`. I switched `&str` to `String` because `&str` without a lifetime is probably not what you want and in any case even further removed from Java `String` than Rust's `String` already is.

However, if you simply *don't care* about the type of the values, it's simpler and more efficient to make `method1` generic:

```
fn method1<T>(my_hash_map: HashMap<String, T>) { ... }
```

Of course, you can also add constraints `T:Trait` to do more interesting things with the values (cf. `Object` allows equality comparisons and hashing).

Comment: why `Box<Any>`, not only `Any`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp `Any` is a trait, not a concrete type. It doesn't have a known size, so you can't store it by value as is the default for types. This is also the case in Java but doesn't matter because all objects are accessed through references/pointers anyway. In Rust, there are multiple kinds of pointers, so you need to decide which you want to use: There's also `&'a Any`, and soon-ish `Rc<Any>`, `Arc<Any>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on rightføld's comment, `Any` is the closest you can really get in Rust, though it *does* come with a major restriction: it is *only* implemented by types which satisfy the `'static` lifetime; that is, you can't treat any type which contains non-static references as an `Any`.

A second complication is that `Object` in Java has reference semantics and gives you shared ownership.  As such, you'd need something like `Rc<RefCell<Any>>` to get something roughly comparable.  Note, however, that this is *heavily discouraged* since it basically moves a lot of checks to runtime.  Something like this should be a fallback of last resort.

Finally, note that, insofar as I'm aware, there's no way to do a dynamic upcast on an `Any` to anything *other* than the erased type; so you can't take a reference to a value that, say, implements `Show`, turn it into an `&Any`, and then upcast to a `&Show`.

Better alternatives, if applicable, include generalising the value type (so use generic functions and structs), using an `enum` if there is a fixed, finite list of types you want to support, or write and implement a custom trait, in that order.

To give you an example of working with `Any`, however, I threw the following together.  Note that we have to try explicitly upcasting to every supported type.

```
#![feature(if_let)]

use std::any::{Any, AnyRefExt};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let val_a = box "blah";
    let val_b = box 42u;
    let val_c = box 3.14159f64;

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("a".into_string(), val_a as Box<Any>);
    map.insert("b".into_string(), val_b as Box<Any>);
    map.insert("c".into_string(), val_c as Box<Any>);

    println!("{}", map);
    splang(&map);
}

fn splang(map: &HashMap<String, Box<Any>>) {
    for (k, v) in map.iter() {
        if let Some(v) = v.downcast_ref::<&str>() {
            println!("[\"{}\"]: &str = \"{}\"", k, *v);
        } else if let Some(v) = v.downcast_ref::<uint>() {
            println!("[\"{}\"]: uint = {}", k, *v);
        } else {
            println!("[\"{}\"]: ? = {}", k, v);
        }
    }
}
```

When run, it outputs:

```
{c: Box<Any>, a: Box<Any>, b: Box<Any>}
["c"]: ? = Box<Any>
["a"]: &str = "blah"
["b"]: uint = 42
```